# jquery/bootstrap file upload plugin on dynamic content not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have several HTML forms that are appended to the page using jquery on change event based on dropdown selected option and one of the fields is an input upload field but the plugin (which also shows a preview of the image) does not work with the dynamic content and I'm guessing is because the plugin is loaded before the content. I do not know how to work around this or what piece of code show on here to seek for help.

Any advise is appreciated. Also, if there is any piece of code that could help identify a possible solution, just let me know and I will update the question.

Comment: have you tried to load/reload the plugin after the content? Try and create an MCVE that reproduces the issue.

Comment: After reading tour sugestion, I found a solution by creating a function using $.getScript(); and then calling the function after the dynamic content is appended and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to call the js file after the dynamic content is appended by using jQuery's $.getScript();

```
function load_script (){
$.getScript ("path/to/js/file/script.js");
}
```

Then I call load_script(); right after the content is appended and it works perfectly, at least for me.

Hope this helps others.